# How to expose posgres in docker on aws to other apps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have a docker instance like this

```
docker run --name my-db-name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:latest
```

running in a server

And I have my golang app wrapped by docker running in the same server

```
func main() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:@192.168.99.100:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable")

    http.HandleFunc("/test", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The above is working in my local by is not working in aws because the ip is not correct.

Since I am using mac, I need to use docker machine ip to connect to the docker postgres db, but in aws I don't

What is a good way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the port from your docker to the port of your host. So you have to add the following:

`-p 5432:5432`

Your command should look like this:

`docker run --name my-db-name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres`